# PHP managed to create and upload files to root of windows server

Tags: php, permissions, windows

I was testing a PHP upload script which created folders and uploaded files. I forgot to make the folder path go from the root, however, the folders where still created.

I checked my Windows servers permissions for the C: drive and nothing seems unusual (just creator, system, admin and users).

How was my php script able to upload to the root? Many thanks!

I'm running windows server enterprise 2007 sp2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP run with the same permissions as the user that you assigned to your web site. Which user exactly is taken into account depends on many things. Here is a short list that should allow you to identify the account in question:

- If you have authentication enabled and are using IE, then you're most likely authenticated locally as yourself. If you're a local administrator, then you can create folder in the root directory and place files in it.
- If you have enabled anonymous "authentication", then you're using the identity of the user you specified in the web site configuration for anonymous users.

Without knowing exactly which version of windows you're using, nothing more can be said about your issue. As a habit, when you ask questions here, please specify what environment your using (OS, version, web server if it applies, framework version, etc.)

Comment: thanks alot for your help, means a lot. I'm running windows server enterprise 2007 sp2, but developing on windows 7 using chrome if that helps.